# Access $Sesssion from helper in cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, helper

a cakePHP newbie here....

I have created a custom helper.

I need to get a session value in this helper and i need to get some data from a table.

How i can make these things possible.

I have tried

```
var $helper=array('Session');
```

but then also when i use

```
$this->Session->read('userid');
```

it returns error

Undefined property: CustomHelper::$Session

here is the helper in detail

```
<?php 
class CssMenuHelper extends Helper{

    var $helpers = array('Html','javascript','Session');

    function createMenu(){

        $gid=$this->Session->read('Auth.Login.group_id');

       }
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay more attention to detail and read [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/102/Including-other-Helpers). The variable is named `var $helpers`, plural.

As for accessing tables from Helpers, you shouldn't. It violates MVC separation. Query the data in the Controller, `set` it to be available in the View and pass it to the Helper function.

Comment: thanks bro...........
var $helpers=array('Session');........
even though after using this the same error

Comment: @deceze bro can u please post a custom helper and show how you are using this in default.ctp